# Heroku SSL - Updating DNS Entries

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns, ssl-certificate

I've recently added SSL Endpoint plugin for Heroku in order to enable SSL.  I've purchased and uploaded certificates successfully, which I've verified by heroku certs command:

```
Endpoint                  Common Name(s)                     Expires               Trusted
------------------------  ---------------------------------  --------------------  -------
app-1234.herokussl.com    mydomain.com mydomain.com.au       2013-08-09 12:26 EST  True
```

The step where I got stuck is configuring DNS (I'm using **Zerigo DNS** provider/plugin for Heroku):

Currently, I have the following DNS config:

Host: **www.mydomain.com**

Type: **CNAME**

Data: **proxy.heroku.com**

On top of that I have a number of A records for mydomain.com which point to various IP addresses.  All the configuration was auto generated by executing the following command:

```
heroku domains:add mydomain.com
```

Any tips on the DNS config for this scenario would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want the CNAME to point to `app-1234.herokussl.com` not `proxy.heroku.com`